# Raspberry Pi 2 durability as a industrial product

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am doing a small project for an industrial product.

The basic behavior of the product is networking through a serial port and ethernet both 24hours all day.

We are considering of using `Raspberry PI 2` for our product.

However, I am curious that using `Raspberry PI` as an industrial product is safe in durability since I know a Raspberry is made for educational intention.

Could we use origin Raspberry PI 2 for an industrial product,

or that is dangerous or we can after some tuning?

If possible, what we Must consider?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-compute-module-new-product/ might be of interest.

Comment: Check the ratings of the components.  Semiconductors are rated for temperature ranges, and classified as commercial, industrial, automotive, and up to military.

Comment: Only you can determine if it will work for your purposes.  You need to build a prototype then put it through any  tests you have determined are required to verify if it will accomplish the project's goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends under what conditions it will work and how critical is your system. Also, the casing is important as with all devices. If you expect it to be under heavy load - mount additional radiators or other cooling equpiment.

My RP2 is working just fine, constantly, for a few months right now - though as all computers - it can crash. So consider having a backup RP2 that will automatically (or at least in quick manner) replace the broken main unit.

Plus, consider the OS - some crash way more often than the other.

Comment: works fine with MQTT , easy to install. But be aware of interferences due to magnetic fields in an industrial environment !  specially with the gpio interface that acts as an antenna